# Specify an address as "to", but don't deliver to them

Tags: email, smtp

I have a service that sends donor's receipt emails after a donation to an organization. These emails contain a summary of the donation, as well as login information so donors can access their account later.

I want the organization getting the donation to be bcc'ed the email sent to the donor. However, I also want to censor the login information contained within.

To do this, my idea was to send the receipt email to the donor with everything. And then take the same email, but censor the login information. Then I'd "to" the donor and bcc the organization. Then when the organization receives the email, they see the email the receipt was sent to, but don't get to see the login information.

The issue is, of course, that when I "to" a recipient, the recipient will actually receive the email. So is there a way to specify the recipient of the email, without actually delivering to them?

Comment: Is it php/perl/... service?  **HOW** do you send emails? There are **many** ways to do it.

Comment: I'm referring to the protocol level. Not a particular language/framework.

Comment: Why don't you just generate 2 different emails with different texts? The one for the organization would be: "someone made a donation to your org.; blah blah blah".

Comment: @PaulJ That would be the best solution IMO (or no notification emails at all!), but for some reason, these organizations are kind of paranoid about this. Don't ask me why :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most internet email today is transmitted via SMTP protocol.

[SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smtp) protocol ([RFC5381](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321)) commands `MAIL FROM` and `RCPT TO` may be unrelated to `From:`, `To:` and `Cc:` headers in message ([RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822)) transmitted after `DATA` command.